# multiple select установить фокус

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic

Есть select вида:

```
<select multiple id="my-select">
  <option value="1">first</option>
  <option value="2">second</option>
  <option value="3">third</option>
</select>
```

Как программно установить фокус на данный селект?

Пишу на ionic 1.3.
Проверю любые ответы.

Comment: Попробуйте `$('#my-select').focus()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал такой метод для выделения элемента:

```
function clickByElement(selector) {
    $timeout(function() {
        var element = $(selector)[0];
        var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
    });
}
```

После добавления $timeout это заработало.

Answer (score 2):

Хоть пост и правильный, но я бы рекомендовал использовать вместо "mousedown" - "click". Все таки вы пишите на IONIC Framework, и это мобильное устройство, и именно click, он с имитирует Вам Touch Event.
И еще что важно, если я не ошибаюсь "mousedown" когда вы соберете платформу IOS не сработает, в то время как на Android все будет ок.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Да вы правы, на ios не работает. Ближайшее время не предоставится возможности проверить - "click" будет работать везде?